# Upgrading Sitecore (4>6)

Tags: sitecore

If i were to upgrade a Sitecore 4 site to a newer Sitecore 6 site, what would then be the correct replacement for the following;

```
protected IWebItem page = State.CurrentItem;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say it is `Sitecore.Context.Item`.

Comment: So "protected page = Sitecore.Context.Item;"?

Comment: in this case `protected Item page = Sitecore.Context.Item;` assuming the context database is `web` now, that is the code is in layout/sublayout, for instance